# HTTP server on pure sockets in python

Tags: python, sockets, http, server

I`m trying to write very simple http server in python. Working version is like this:

```
def run(self, host='localhost',port=8000):
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        s.bind((host,port))
        s.listen(1)
        while True:
            connection, adress = s.accept()
            with connection:
                data = b''
                while True:
                    recived = connection.recv(1024)
                    data += recived
                    if len(recived) < 1024:
                        break

                if data != b'':
                    handle_request(data,connection)
```

It works , but i have some misunderstanding whats going on. 
As i understand, socket "s" accept connection from the client -> and return new socket object "connection"  from which i can read what client sends to me and send response. I read data from connection until client send empty line b''. After this point TCP part ends and I pass recived bytes to handler which parse recived data as HTTP.

**Qestions: At this point i read all the data which client send to me, but if i want to limit max size of HTTP request, should i just do something like this:**

```
..................................

    with connection:
        data = b''
        request_size_limit=1024*100 # some desired http request max size
        while True:
            recived = connection.recv(1024)
            data += recived
            if len(recived) < 1024 or len(data) > request_size_limit:
                break             
            if data != b'':
                handle_request(data,connection)
```

1. If i do something like this how can I inform client, that for example i have at most 1024*1024 free bytes of RAM and I can`t handle requests larger than this?
2. If clients want to send more that this limit, he must send several separated requests which will contain 1 part of necessary data?
3. Or for example for big POST request i must parse each recv(1024) while i found \r\n\r\n sequence , check content length  and recv() content length by parts 1024b into some file and proceed after?

Comment: Why are you writing your own web server? Vs using flask or Django

Comment: If you are too fast, or the request is exactly a multiple of 1024 bytes, you will terminate reading too soon, or never terminate.  TCP isn't guaranteed to arrive all at once, so you need to look at the data as you get it and wait for the blank line (for a GET), or read the Content-Length (or more complicated schemes) for POST.

Comment: If the request has a size of N*1024 it will simply hang within `recv` after reading the full request since it expects the final `recv` to return less than 1024 bytes. You actually have to check for the end of request header (empty line - see the HTTP standard for the details) after each `recv` and then also check if there is a request body based on the request method and the `content-length` header.

Comment: @JohnH i need server for micropython -> so i cant use existing.

Comment: @Max thx, so read chunk - parse chunk - wait for another chunk ... wait for end of request.

Comment: @AlexQ. That's right!  You should be able to pull in httplib though or something from the standard library; it's written in pure python afaik.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thx

Answer (score 0):

A1) If you can't handle the request because it is too large consider just closing the connection. Alternatively you can read (and discard) everything they send and then respond with a 413 Request Took Large.

A2) You'll need to work out a protocol for sending just parts of a request at a time. HTTP doesn't do this natively.

A3) If you can read the whole request in chunks and save it to a file, then it sounds like you have a solution to the 1024*1024 RAM limit, doesn't it?

But fix the issues with reading chunked data off the socket.